# How can I download a basic authentication-protected file in a Chocolatey install script?

Tags: basic-authentication, chocolatey

The [Install-ChocolateyZipPackage](https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/wiki/HelpersInstallChocolateyZipPackage) commandlet does not seem to support basic authentication when it comes to downloading files, i.e. via an URL such as `https://user:password@example.com/file.zip`. How can I work around this in my Chocolatey install script, i.e. download the file in question (e.g. `https://user:password@example.com/file.zip`) before I install it via Install-ChocolateyZipPackage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thomas put up a good answer in the group forum - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/chocolatey/e4lcPIrLhis/vfSUVe0SZcIJ

> As far as I know, authentication is not supported. But you could
>   specify wget as dependency and use that to download the file.
>
> I use it in one of my packages for authentication and it works fine:
>   https://chocolatey.org/packages/rukerneltool#files (look at chocolateyInstall.ps1)
>
> On Linux, wget would be the first choice to handle such things in a
>   Bash script.
>
> But if the software you want to make a package of is Open Source, you
>   could integrate it directly into the package. That makes it easier.

Code for this is (in case it is later changed:

```
$webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$webClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.Networkcredential($username, $password)
Write-Output $('Downloading' + $url + '…')
$webClient.DownloadFile($url, $zipFilePath)
```

Comment: All links are not available.

Comment: Thanks for that note. Should have brought that in. Let me update with a new link

Comment: updated to https://chocolatey.org/packages/rukerneltool#files (chocolateyInstall.ps1 is there for inspection)

Answer (score 0):

I use a similar way without wget, to fetch artifacts from our company's buildserver

```
$packageName = 'mycompanypackage'
$installerType = 'exe'
$username = 'chocolatey'
$password = '************'
$url = 'http://bamboo.mycompany.com/browse/DP-RS/latestSuccessful/artifact/JOB1/Setup/setup.exe'
$downloadFile = $url.Substring($url.LastIndexOf("/") + 1)
$url = $url+'?os_authType=basic'
$url64 = $url
$silentArgs = '/VERYSILENT /NORESTART /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES'

if (Test-Path "$downloadFile") {Remove-Item "$downloadFile"}

$webclient = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$credCache = new-object System.Net.CredentialCache
$creds = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username, $password)
$credCache.Add($url, "Basic", $creds)
$webclient.Credentials = $credCache

$webclient.DownloadFile($url, $downloadFile)

Install-ChocolateyInstallPackage "$packageName" "$installerType" "$silentArgs" "$downloadFile"
```